# How can I get the column index in each row when the value is 1 in python?

Tags: python, arrays, list

In:

```
 p= np.array([[0,  1,  0,  1],
              [0,  0,  0,  0],
              [1,  0,  0,  0],
              [0,  0,  1,  0]])
```

How can I get the column index in each row when the value is 1.

output1: For example, the first row has 1 in column 1 and 3, then we store these values.

```
[[1,3],[], [0], [2]]
```

Then, +1 every value for ease of counting and put 0 in [] when there is no 1 in array p.

output2:

```
[[2,4],[0], [1], [3]]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use comprehensions:

```
res1 = [[idx+1 for idx, val in enumerate(row) if val] for row in p]
res2 = [[0] if a == [] else a for a in res1] 
print(res2)
```

gives:

```
[[2, 4], [0], [1], [3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

use two level iter to get this.

```
    p = np.array([[0, 1, 0, 1],
                  [0, 0, 0, 0],
                  [1, 0, 0, 0],
                  [0, 0, 1, 0]])
    res = []
    for row in p:
        tmp = []
        for idx, value in enumerate(row):
            if value == 1:
                tmp.append(idx+1)
        if len(tmp) == 0:
            tmp.append(0)
        res.append(tmp)
    print(res)
```

output

```
[[2, 4], [0], [1], [3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.nonzero`

```
lst = [[val + 1 if val else 0 for val in np.nonzero(lst)[0]] for lst in p]
print(lst) # [[2, 4], [], [0], [3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Short one-liner using np.where:

```
[list(np.where(r==1)[0]+1) or [0] for r in p]

[[2, 4], [0], [1], [3]]
```